# Что такое legacy code?

Tags: терминология

Не могу найти перевод. 
Можете объяснить в двух словах что это такое? Что за понятие?

Comment: Посмотрите foldoc (Free On-Line Dictionary of Computing). Правда там определение {legacy code} ссылается на определение {legacy system} http://www.foldoc.org

Comment: legacy код - это код доставшийся в наследство от предыдущих разработчиков.

Comment: `@deprecated` - это не тег, а аннотация. Она служит для пометки элементов публичного API, которые более не рекомендованы к применению и будут убраны в одной из следующих версий библиотеки.

Comment: @ Grundy , то есть если этот код достался в наследство от предыдущих разработчиков, то он по определению -  legacy код? И он не может быть 'not legacy'?

Comment: То есть legacy можно сказать, что весь код legacy включая import классов. В широком смысле весь код унаследован?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Legacy code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_code) — тяжелая наследственность : ) Устаревший код, который более не поддерживается и не обновляется, но используется. Второе значение — код от сторонних разработчиков, или из старых версий.

Comment: "Тяжелая наследственность" - это сильно !

IMHO все таки более правильно второе значение, причем с уточнением от @Barmaley о традиционности.

Answer (score 41):

Суммирорав все определения, которые встречались, для себя вывел следующее.

**Legacy code** — код, подпадающий  под один или несколько признаков:

- написан другими разработчиками,
     возможно, уже недоступными для
     контакта;
- не покрыт юнит-тестами;
- сохранён для совместимости с предыдущими версиями системы;
- устарел и/или более не поддерживается в связи с развитием системы (написан на предыдущем языке, под старую архитектуру, аппаратную платформу, операционную систему  и т.д.).

Answer (score 19):

Требование "опыт работы с legacy кодом" в вакансии означает, что вам достанется код, написанный лет 10-20 назад давно уволившимися программистами. Не исключено, что он изначально был плохо написан, что требования к проекту менялись уже много раз и каждый раз код правился как придётся в режиме жёсткого дедлайна, что документацию никто не писал и рефакторинг не делал. Поэтому вместо того чтобы писать новый код на прогрессивных технологиях, вам большую часть времени придётся разбираться в старом и править его, ловя потом каскады багов. Добро пожаловать в чудесный мир кровавого энтерпрайза, основного потребителя Java.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 11):

[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks) все написал верно, но все таки уточню: вообще термин Legacy в программировании означает прилагательное означающее принадлежность к традиционному. Скажем, Legacy Driver - означает драйвер от производителя и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё бывает *"доставшийся по наследству legacy code"*, который никто не знает как работает. Только программист здесь вряд ли поможет - здесь нужен либо аналитик, либо [data scientist](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), а программист максимум, что сможет, это интерфейс для них написать, если его там нету,
т. е. вывести на форму то, что возможно, из того, что есть в коде.

[image: Честно сжыженый legacy code]